# Regular expression to find string prefix in Python grammar

Tags: python, regex

When you define a string in Python, it may have a prefix that is any mixture of the letters `b`, `r` and `u`, uppercase or lowercase, in any order, as long as there's at most one of each letter, and `b` and `u` can't appear together. Then there's either `'`, or `"`, or `'''`, or `"""`.

I'm interested in making a regular expression to capture the start of the string, up to the opening quote(s). Example matches:

```
br'
'
r"""
Ur'
B"
"
```

Each of these should be a match.

How can I write a regex to match these?

Comment: `(br'|'|r"""|Ur'|B"|")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can't do "up to one of each in any order", so we have to pre-generate the possible prefix combinations.

Luckily, we can make it case-insensitive, and we can make the quote-marks a separate expression; we end up with

```
import re

reg = re.compile("((?:b|u|r|br|ur|rb|ru)?(?:\'(?:\'\')?|\"(?:\"\")?))", re.I)
```

which we can test like

```
def test_reg():
    good_tests = ["br'", "'", 'r"""', "Ur'", 'B"', '"']
    for t in good_tests:
        assert reg.match(t).group(0) == t, "Failed good test {}".format(t)

    bad_tests  = ["bU'", "bb'", 'Uru"']
    for t in bad_tests:
        assert reg.match(t) is None, "Failed bad test {}".format(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a regex string like this:

```
r'regex(string|String)$'
```

Here's some code I use to do regex in python:

```
string = "hello world"
match = re.search(r'(l{2})', string)
print str(match.groups())
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clear that it's not "please teach me what regular expressions are and how to use them in Python."